# Encrypt a string that is of constant length when encrypted

Tags: algorithm, encryption

Say, I have a string that is a chat message, and its length in characters can be, for example, from 1 to 200.

How do I encrypt it the way so that independently of the length of the incoming string, always produces the encrypted string of fixed length, say, 400 characters?

Are there encryption algorithms that provide this functionality or what technique should I use to achieve this result?

If I choose to pad the original string to `n` symbols, then what algorithms produce an output string of the same length for different strings of the same length? I noticed that the most of algorithms produce strings that have different lengthed strings for the same input string, like "Hello!" and "MewMew".

Comment: What if the original message is longer than 400 characters?

Comment: Most block-level cyphers produce cyphertexts that are a multiple of some value. Chances are the default cypher in your environment already fulfills the requirement - and if not, you can always pad by hand.

Comment: May I ask why the variable length is an issue? i.e. what problem are you solving by having a fixed length string? e.g. are there are other items stored in one concatenated string? There may be other ways of indicating the length of the string.

Comment: @RyanVincent I would guess it is to prevent leaking information about the string being stored

Comment: Yes, I don't want to give a clue about the message content - if it's just "Hi!" or something else which is longer and detailed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pad your message to the length you want prior to encryption.

A block cipher like AES would always produce an predictable output size that are dictated by the size of input. Here a message of size n would produce an encrypted message of size n+1 (assuming padding mode) rounded up to nearest block of 16 bytes. So a message of size 384-399 bytes would produce output of 400 bytes.

Comment: I think it's the way I am going to make it work, please have a look at the update in the question.

Comment: The question is: pad with what? standard PKCS#7 padding cannot be applied in this case. Can you propose a padding scheme that is unambiguous?

Comment: Fair enough. Was not thinking on a padding in the cipher, but just something homegrown prior to encrypt... I guess my update the the answer regarding sizes confused that  .. Anyway - put a size in the start of the message, and "pad" the end of the message with random data to the desired size.. then encrypt.